# IMGKit returning corrupted image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, imgkit

I have the following code in Rails 3 application's controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.jpeg do
    image = IMGKit.new("http://www.google.com").to_img(:jpg)
    send_data(image, type: "image/jpeg", filename: "data.jpeg", disposition: "inline")
  end
end
```

I expect that when I ask for a jpeg I get back a jpeg of the Google home page.  However, I get back an image that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhHOl.jpg).  What am I doing wrong?

I'm on Windows 7, and the wkhtmltoimage command works fine from the command line.  I have ruby verion ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32].